# How to construct a xpath or css locator to identify the element using Selenium and Java

Tags: java, selenium, selenium-webdriver, xpath, css-selectors

Here is my Html:

```html
<div class="x-form-item " tabindex="-1" id="ext-gen118">
    <label for="ext-comp-1060" style="width:40px;" class="x-form-item-label" id="ext-gen119">Name:</label>
    <div class="x-form-element" id="x-form-el-ext-comp-1060" style="padding-left:45px">
        <div class="x-form-field-wrap x-form-field-trigger-wrap x-trigger-wrap-focus" id="ext-gen120" style="width: 168px;">
            <input type="text" size="16" autocomplete="off" id="ext-comp-1060" name="ext-comp-1060" class="x-form-text x-form-field x-form-focus" style="width: 143px;" title="">
            <span class="x-form-twin-triggers" id="ext-gen121">
                <img src="/mco/extjs/resources/images/default/s.gif" alt="" class="x-form-trigger x-form-clear-trigger" id="ext-gen122" style="display: none;">
                <img src="/mco/extjs/resources/images/default/s.gif" alt="" class="x-form-trigger x-form-search-trigger" id="ext-gen123">
            </span>
        </div>
    </div>
    <div class="x-form-clear-left"></div>
</div>
```

I have tried below  id "ext-comp-1060 is dynamic so that I cannot use.

```
xpath = "//div[@class='x-form-field-wrap x-form-field-trigger-wrap x-trigger-wrap-focus']//input[@class='input.x-form-text.x-form-field.x-form-focus']"

css = "input.x-form-text.x-form-field.x-form-focus"
```

In My application same input text field I have to use two times one after other
first time it's working I have tried like this:

```
Wait wait = new FluentWait<WebDriver>(driver)
                .withTimeout(10, TimeUnit.SECONDS)
               .pollingEvery(3, TimeUnit.SECONDS);
       wait.until(ExpectedConditions.visibilityOfElementLocated(By.xpath("//label[contains(text(),'Name:')]")));
       ((JavascriptExecutor) driver).executeScript("arguments[0].click();", labelName);

searchName =@FindBy(css = "input.x-form-text.x-form-field.x-form-focus")
private WebElement searchByName;

searchByName.sendKeys(name);
```

But At same time second time it's not working

Comment: Duplicate [Which version of TLS is supported by JavaMail 1.4?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/58638567/which-version-of-tls-is-supported-by-javamail-1-4)

Comment: @Ruzal Yumaev It is not related to TLS

Answer (score 2):

Your `webelement` is dynamic so you can look for partial matching for element's attribute like `Id` , `class` and `Name`

**Wait for element**

```
    By byCss=By.cssSelector("input[id^='ext-comp-']");
    By byXpath= By.xpath("//label[.='Name:']//input");

    WebDriverWait wait = new WebDriverWait(driver, 30);
    wait.until(ExpectedConditions.elementToBeClickable(byCss));

    WebDriverWait wait = new WebDriverWait(driver, 30);
    wait.until(ExpectedConditions.elementToBeClickable(byXpath));
```

**Find element and Click:**

```
    WebElement element = driver.findElement(byCss); 


    WebElement element = driver.findElement(byXpath);

    element.click();
```

Answer (score 1):

To `click()` within the desired element you need to induce *WebDriverWait* for the `elementToBeClickable()` and you can use either of the following  [Locator Strategies](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/48369043/official-locator-strategies-for-the-webdriver/48376890#48376890):

- `cssSelector`:

  ```
  new WebDriverWait(driver, 20).until(ExpectedConditions.elementToBeClickable(By.cssSelector("label.x-form-item-label[id^='ext-gen'][for^='ext-comp-']"))).click();
  ```
- `xpath`:

  ```
  new WebDriverWait(driver, 20).until(ExpectedConditions.elementToBeClickable(By.xpath("//label[@class='x-form-item-label' and starts-with(@id, 'ext-gen')][starts-with(@for, 'ext-comp-') and text()='Name:']"))).click();
  ```

Answer (score 0):

Does only the numbers change or the whole word?
If only the numbers change you can use this as Css locator:

```
input[id^='ext-comp']
```

Comment: Please add this as a comment of the question as it is definitely not an answer

Comment: edited my answer in somethign usefull anyway, thanks for adjusting @D.Lawrence

Answer (score 0):

I updated your xpath using contains, try this:

```
xpath = "//div[contains(@class, 'x-form-field-wrap']/input[contains(@class, 'x-form-text']"
```

Answer (score 0):

Use the following `XPATH` which will identify the input element with reference to label tag `Name:`

> //label[text()='Name:']/following-sibling::div[1]//input

To handle dynamic element Induce `WebDriverWait` and wait for `elementToBeClickable()`

```
new WebDriverWait(driver, 20).until(ExpectedConditions.elementToBeClickable(By.xpath("//label[text()='Name:']/following-sibling::div[1]//input"))).sendKeys("Hello");
```

Comment: Thanks all I have tried all solutions but nothing work for me

Comment: Actually I have two same input text field in my app so first one is working I have tried like this:   css = "input.x-form-text.x-form-field.x-form-focus" with wait but at same time for second time its not working

Answer (score 0):

You can try below given xpath.

```
//div[@class='x-form-element']//child::input[@type='text' AND size='16']
```

I am accessing the input field using type and size attribute of the web element through a parent level element.

Hope this will solve your problem.